# How to calculate gl_FragCoord in glsl

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

Ok, in my GLSL fragment shader I want to be able to calculate the distance of the fragment from a particular line in space.

The result of this is that I am first trying to use a varying vec2 set in my vertex shader to mirror what ends up in `gl_FragCoord`:

```
varying vec2 fake_frag_coord;
//in vertex shader:
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
fake_frag_coord=(gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex).xy;
```

Now in the fragment shader I expect:

```
gl_FragCoord.xy==fake_frag_coord
```

But it does not. What operation does the pipeline do on `gl_Position` to turn it into `gl_FragCoord` that I am neglecting to do on `fake_frag_coord`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

gl_FragCoord is screen coordinates, so you'd need to have information about the screen size and such to produce it based on the Position. The fake_frag_coord you've produced will correspond to a point in the screen in normalized device coordinates I think (-1 to 1). So if you were to multiply by half the screen's size in a particular dimension, and then add that size, you'd get actual screen pixels.

Comment: I was wrong about you being wrong, but right about using gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex potentially introducing compute errors.

Comment: Nitpick: that will actually give you clip-space coordinates rather than normalised device coordinates, since you're not performing the perspective division which happens during the rasterisation process (between the vertex shader and fragment shader). http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html#name1

Comment: @Pike65 That's not just a nitpick, it should results in completely different values for a perspective projection.

Comment: dose `gl_FragCoord.xy==gl_Position.xy/gl_Position.w` will do the perspective division?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex computed in a shader is not always what the fixed function pipeline yields. To get identical results, do fake_frag_coord = ftransform().

Edit:

And then scale it with your screen dimensions.

Comment: ftransform produces the position, not the fragcoord. The question isn't asking how to get the position.

Comment: My answer wasn't completely wrong. You need to scale fake_frag_coord with your screen dimensions, but you may get different results depending on whether you use fake_frag_coord = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex or = ftransform().

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had more rep so I could nitpick too.
Here's what I know.
OpenGL performs the Divide-By-W automatically for you, so by the time a position arrives in a fragment shader, it's already in NDC coordinates, and by then W will be 1.0, the only time you need to divide by W is if you want to do the same math on the CPU side, and get the same results, OR, if you for some odd reason, wanted to get NDC coordinates within your vertex shader.

Comment: `gl_FragCoord` is **not** in NDC. It's in window coordinates.

Answer (score -2):

```
varying vec2 fake_frag_coord;
//in vertex shader:

fake_frag_coord=(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex).xy
```